# Accessing User.Identity from Master Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm trying to access User.Identity from my master page so I can figure out which user is logged in, however I can't get it to work. If I import `System.Security.Principal` in my master page it makes no difference:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Security.Principal" %>
```

I can access it fine if I try within a Controller.

Any idea what I need to do?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

What about through `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity`?

Answer (score 8):

`<%=HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name %>` Will display the current users name
`HttpContext.Current.User` will get the IPrincipal object.

Here is a master page that only displays the Username in the title:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" />
    </title>
    <link href="../../Content/Style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="page">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="title">
                <h1 id="maintitle">
                    <%=HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name %>
                </h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="main">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server" />
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

I think Its Work

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString()
```

or

```
Page.User.Identity.Name.ToString()
```

Comment: What does this add compared to the accepted answer?

Comment: `Page.User` seems cleaner somehow than `HttpContext.Current.User`. Just a matter of taste since they do the same thing.

Comment: I am not understandnign what are you sayinh me

Answer (score 2):

You can use `HttpContext.Current.User.Name` but you need to remember that the `Master Page` code is executed only after the slave page code. So you can use this variable as long as you are not performing any security logic in the master page.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this from:

> `Context.User.Identity.Name`